# Maven doesn't download dependencies: "The repository system is offline"

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I'm not comfortable with Maven, but I managed to make it work for a while with Netbeans. But suddenly, Maven refuses to download new dependencies :

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project matheos: Could not resolve dependencies for project lecoleopensource:matheos:jar:1.4.4-SNAPSHOT: The repository system is offline but the artifact org.docx4j:docx4j-ImportXHTML:jar:3.2.2 is not available in the local repository.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:258)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:201)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project lecoleopensource:matheos:jar:1.4.4-SNAPSHOT: The repository system is offline but the artifact org.docx4j:docx4j-ImportXHTML:jar:3.2.2 is not available in the local repository.
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:185)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: The repository system is offline but the artifact org.docx4j:docx4j-ImportXHTML:jar:3.2.2 is not available in the local repository.
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:375)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:183)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: The repository system is offline but the artifact org.docx4j:docx4j-ImportXHTML:jar:3.2.2 is not available in the local repository.
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:538)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:358)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: The repository system is offline but the artifact org.docx4j:docx4j-ImportXHTML:jar:3.2.2 is not available in the local repository.
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:348)
    ... 26 more
```

Something is apparently offline, but I don't understand why and how to fix this.

Here is a part of my pom file :

```
    <dependencies>
        <!-- docx4j : converts html to docx -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>docx4j</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- pdf2dom : converts pdf to html -->
        <!--dependency>
                <groupId>net.sf.cssbox</groupId>
                <artifactId>pdf2dom</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency-->


    </dependencies>
```

What I don't understand is that it used to work fine until now...

I don't understand Maven very well, so tell me if I should have given other details. Thank you !

**EDIT :** I removed the repository section, still the same. I edited the artefactID to docx4j, still the same.

Comment: look at this message `Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project lecoleopensource:matheos:jar:1.4.4-SNAPSHOT: The repository system is offline but the artifact org.docx4j:docx4j-ImportXHTML:jar:3.2.2 is not available in the local repository.`. Maven tries to download dependencies for org.docx4j, is unable to do it, and tries to find org.docx4j in your local repo. And unable to do that.

Comment: Here is [the pom declaration example for docx4j version 3.2.2](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.docx4j/docx4j/3.2.2)

Comment: @Rafael Osipov : I understand more or less the issue. What I don't understand is why maven is "unable to do it" like you say...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply remove the repositories section you have defined. Neither you need to define a local repository, because it is still defined in the settings.xml Maven configuration, nor you would place project dependencies under src/main/resources.

**Update**

Could it be you are running Maven in "offline mode"? Have a look at your Netbeans preferences -> Java -> Maven and your run configuration, if there is an "-o" parameter.

Comment: Ok, I removed it, but it didn't solve my problem... I did it because I had a "not Maven" dependency and I didn't know where to put it so I put it in src/main/resources...

Comment: Those dependencies can be attached by setting the scope to "system".